# How to have text in between form inputs

Tags: html, css, reactjs, forms

I'm trying to make a form with various inputs and between these inputs I want text. Here's what it should look like:
[image: Each of the lines with text underneath are inputs]

I have had no problem putting the text underneath, but simultaneously having text that goes between each input has been hard. Originally I tried to do it as a series of textareas inside of a div, but that made the text underneath work improperly. Any idea how I can do both? Here's what it currently looks like:

[image: Current look]

And here's the code I have for it:

React:

```js
<form>
                                    <div id="form_fields_div">
                                        <fieldset>
                                            <input type="text" name="text_box_number_1_page_6" id="text_box_number_1_page_6" />
                                            <label for="text_box_number_1_page_6">(a feeling you don’t like) </label>
                                        </fieldset>
                                        <h2>. I do</h2>
                                    
                                    
                                        <fieldset>
                                            <input type="text" name="text_box_number_2_page_6" id="text_box_number_2_page_6" />
                                            <label for="text_box_number_2_page_6">(an activity that makes you feel better)</label>
                                        </fieldset>
                                        <h2>to make me feel less</h2>
                                    
                                    
                                        <fieldset>
                                            <input type="text" name="text_box_number_3_page_6" id="text_box_number_3_page_6" />
                                            <label for="text_box_number_3_page_6">(the feeling you don’t like)</label>
                                        </fieldset>
                                        <h2>That means that</h2>
                                    
                                
                                        <fieldset>
                                            <input type="text" name="text_box_number_3_page_6" id="text_box_number_3_page_6" />
                                            <label for="text_box_number_3_page_6">(the activity that makes you feel better)</label>
                                        </fieldset>
                                        <h2>is a coping strategy.</h2>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
```

and css:

```css
form {
    width: 89.5em;
    overflow: hidden;
    
    border: none;
    
  }
   fieldset {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 10em;
    margin: 0 1em 0 0;
    border: none;
    
  }
    fieldset:last-child {
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  fieldset > input,
  fieldset > label {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 15px;
  }
  fieldset > input {
    width: 80%;
    font-size: 25px;
  }

  #form_fields_div {
      display: inline;
      white-space: nowrap;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create form item wrapped by `span` tag with display `inline-flex` and direction `column` to display the label under the input

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.2.19/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Test</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.2.19/tailwind.min.css"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <div id="form_fields_div">
        For example, sometimes I do feel
        <span class="inline-flex flex-col">
          <input
            class="border-b border-black"
            type="text"
            name="text_box_number_1_page_6"
            id="text_box_number_1_page_6"
          />
          <label for="id1">(a feeling you don’t like)</label>
        </span>
        <span>. I do</span>
        <span class="inline-flex flex-col">
          <input
            class="border-b border-black"
            type="text"
            name="text_box_number_2_page_6"
            id="text_box_number_2_page_6"
          />
          <label for="id1">(an activity that makes you feel better)</label>
        </span>

        <span>to make me feel less</span>

        <span class="inline-flex flex-col">
          <input
            class="border-b border-black"
            type="text"
            name="text_box_number_3_page_6"
            id="text_box_number_3_page_6"
          />
          <label for="text_box_number_3_page_6"
            >(the feeling you don’t like)</label
          >
        </span>
        <span>That means that</span>

        <span class="inline-flex flex-col">
          <input
            class="border-b border-black"
            type="text"
            name="text_box_number_3_page_6"
            id="text_box_number_3_page_6"
          />
          <label for="text_box_number_3_page_6"
            >(the activity that makes you feel better)</label
          >
        </span>
        <span>is a coping strategy.</span>
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is it thank you! One question though which is what does the linked stylesheet do here? Without it it didn't work so I'm curious what it is that's making this suddenly work.

Comment: Actually React seems to really hate external CSS files so I'm having a lot of trouble making this work locally (it keeps applying the CSS file globally). Is there a way to take the info in this and just take the stuff that's important to this? I don't know how to read the file as it's really mushed. Sorry to ask more of you but I'm at a loss...

Comment: @zichyboy [css module](https://css-tricks.com/css-modules-part-1-need/) will resolve you problem. You can put your css within `css-file-name.module.css` It will work locally

Comment: I still had some trouble with it being global (I think I needed to make some changes to my webpacker/package file) but using SCSS/SASS with nesting ended up being the trick! Thank you for all of your help!

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code I used:

JS File:

```js
import '../extcss.scss';

<form>
    <div className="extcss" id="form_fields_div">
        <p>For example, sometimes I do feel<br/><br/></p>
        <span className="inline-flex flex-col">
            <input
                onChange={event => this.handleChange(event)}
                defaultValue={this.getValue("text_box_number_1_page_6_sheet_4")}
                className="border-b border-black text_box_inputs"
                type="text"
                name="text_box_number_1_page_6_sheet_4"
                id="text_box_number_1_page_6_sheet_4"
            />
            <label for="text_box_number_1_page_6_sheet_4">(a feeling you don't like)</label>
        </span>
        <span className='side_text'>. I do&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
        <span className="inline-flex flex-col">
            <input
                onChange={event => this.handleChange(event)}
                defaultValue={this.getValue("text_box_number_2_page_6_sheet_4")}
                className="border-b border-black text_box_inputs"
                type="text"
                name="text_box_number_2_page_6_sheet_4"
                id="text_box_number_2_page_6_sheet_4"
            />
            <label for="text_box_number_2_page_6_sheet_4">(an activity that makes you feel better)</label>
        </span>

        <span className='side_text'>&nbsp;&nbsp;to make me feel less&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>

        <span className="inline-flex flex-col">
        <input
            onChange={event => this.handleChange(event)}
            defaultValue={this.getValue("text_box_number_3_page_6_sheet_4")}
            className="border-b border-black text_box_inputs"
            type="text"
            name="text_box_number_3_page_6_sheet_4"
            id="text_box_number_3_page_6_sheet_4"
        />
        <label for="text_box_number_3_page_6_sheet_4"
            >(the feeling you don't like)</label
        >
        </span>
        <span className='side_text'>&nbsp;&nbsp;That means that&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>

        <span className="inline-flex flex-col">
        <input
            onChange={event => this.handleChange(event)}
            defaultValue={this.getValue("text_box_number_4_page_6_sheet_4")}
            className="border-b border-black text_box_inputs"
            type="text"
            name="text_box_number_4_page_6_sheet_4"
            id="text_box_number_4_page_6_sheet_4"
        />
        <label for="text_box_number_4_page_6_sheet_4"
            >(the activity that makes you feel better)</label
        >
        </span>
        <span className='side_text'>&nbsp;&nbsp;is a coping strategy.</span>
    </div>
</form>
```

extcss.scss:

```css
.extcss{
  /* Code from external css file copied here */
}
```